# passport redirect after login with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

i'm confused about how to redirect the page after successfully logged in using passport.

in node.js code

```
app.post('/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local',
{ 
    successRedirect: '/index.html#/page1', // why this not working ?
    failureRedirect: '/login',
}));
```

in Angular routeProvider code,

```
app.controller('authController', function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $scope.user = {username:'', password:''};
    $scope.alert = '';

    $scope.login = function(user) {
        $http.post('/auth/login', user).
            success(function(data) {
                console.log("you are at /auth/login 0");
                $scope.loggedUser = data;
                //$location.path('/index.html'); // why this not working ?
                $window.location.href = "/index.html#/page2"; // this works
            }).
            error(function() {
                console.log("you are at /auth/login 1");
                $scope.alert = 'Login failed'
            });
    };

    ....
});
```

btw, my default homepage is set to login.html, not index.html.

The question is, why the redirect in successRedirect in node.js code is not working ? If i have to do it in Angualr code, What's the correct way to do it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

use `$location.path("/");` to redirect in angular

**EDIT**

you have to do a file like that

```
angular.module('authModule', [])
   .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/auth/login.html',
      })    
      .....         
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

so you can use `$location.path("/login");` to redirect login page

Comment: My default homepage is login.html, not index.html. So if use "/", it'll go back to login page again, which is not what i wanted. Then if i use "/home" which routes to index.html in $routeProvider, believe nothing shows up.

Comment: @user3552178 check the edit answer, maybe the problem because  `/home` not show is because you have no defined the route